# Creating new records from within a jOOQ record listener

Tags: kotlin, jooq

I am currently exploring the possibilities - and limits - of the jOOQ [RecordListener](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-execution/crud-with-updatablerecords/crud-record-listener/).

In toying with it I was testing whether I could create new data in the context of a listener invocation. A potential scenario could be this: when library X (using jOOQ) inserts records I want to get notified and insert additional records as part of the same transaction.

Based my poking through the documentation and writing test code this does not seem to be possible?

**1. Test**

Idea: when a `FOO` was inserted also insert a `BAR`

```
object Test : DefaultRecordListener() {
    override fun insertEnd(ctx: RecordContext?) {
        val table = (ctx?.record() as org.jooq.TableRecord<*>).table
        if (table == FOO) {
            val t = ctx.dsl().newRecord(BAR)
            t.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
            t.creationTimeUtc = ZonedDateTime.now()
            t.insert()
        }
    }
}
```

Result: `BAR` is there but `FOO` is lost

**2. Test**

Idea: same, but create a new transaction in the listener with the idea of it taking part in the transaction of the outer scope

```
object Test : DefaultRecordListener() {
    override fun insertEnd(ctx: RecordContext?) {
        val table = (ctx?.record() as org.jooq.TableRecord<*>).table
        if (table == FOO) {
            ctx
                .dsl()
                .transaction { c ->
                    val t = c.dsl().newRecord(BAR)
                    t.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
                    t.creationTimeUtc = ZonedDateTime.now()
                    t.insert()
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Result: error triggered from library X as it can't commit the original insert of `FOO`, no `BAR` created of course

Comment: There is no reason why 1) shouldn't work (although, you should probably create a derived configuration without record listeners, to prevent a `StackOverflowError`). Why is `FOO` lost?

Comment: I don't know yet. I thought it was because the RL concept didn't allow for such manipulations. Looks like I need to dig in there. Thanks for hint about the derived config. There's no risk for SOE since I check for `FOO` and insert `BAR` but still..

Comment: I picked this up again after a while but I'm no smarter now than I was then. Even with jOOQ trace logging turned on I have zero indication why the `FOO` insert is lost. It's illogical. Since I am implementing `insertEnd()` the `FOO` record should already have been inserted by the time the listener is invoked. However, the SQL log clearly shows that jOOQ issues an insert for `BAR` but none for `FOO`.